# Tag merge request: 'british-citizens' into 'uk-citizens'

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-synonyms

The [british-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/british-citizens) tag seems to be encompassed by the (much larger) [uk-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uk-citizens) tag.

Actually I just noticed that [brithish-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brithish-citizens) (yes, spelled like that) is already a synonym for [uk-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uk-citizens).

Please forgive me if there is a subtle difference between these that I'm not aware of (if there is, this should be made clear in the appropriate tag wikis).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tag synonym created. The old [brithish-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brithish-citizens) seems to have been a typo.